# Android asynctask should call method of parent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

In my `main class`, i call `map activity`. After creating map and take location and show user in map, i call `asynctask` to connect certain `sites` to get events.

After i take `location` as `string`, i need to `geocode` to get `lat` and `lng` values to show user around places as `list` or in `map`.

In `background` of `asynctask`, i already `connect` websites. It takes 1-2 minutes.

After that, should i call method of parent class for geocode, passing string locaitions as paramter? Because in that background method , i cant import geocoder and i can not define private things and i cant import spherical to computedistance.

Is it good thing to call parent class method?

this is geocoder but i couldnot add to my project yet. It is basic now, i will improve.

```
if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    try {
        From_geocode = geocoder.getFromLocationName(" berlin ", 1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!From_geocode.isEmpty()) {{
        System.out.println("2");
        From_geocode.get(0).getLatitude(); // getting
        // latitude
        From_geocode.get(0).getLongitude();

        sLat = From_geocode.get(0).getLatitude();
        sLong = From_geocode.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng latlng=new LatLng(sLat,sLong);
        LatLng latlng2=new LatLng(41,28);

      Log.d("mytag", "LATITUTE=====" + sLat + "   LONGITUTE=====" + sLong);
        Log.d("mytag", "LATITUTE=====" + latlng2.latitude + "   LONGITUTE=====" +latlng2.longitude);
    //    for(Address adr: From_geocode){
          //  Log.d("mytag",adr.toString());
      //  }


        Log.d("mytag",String.valueOf(SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, latlng2)) );
    }}
    }
```

this is snippet from doitbackground

```
if (eventEndDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)>=currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)//if today
                && eventStartDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)<=currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                && eventStartDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1 &&//and hour,start in 1 hour
                currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= eventEndDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {

            Log.d(TAG, "name:" + name + "\nlocation:" + location);
            //Log.d(TAG,"type:"+type);
            Log.d(TAG, "sdate:" + formatter.format(sDate.getTime()));
            Log.d(TAG, "edate:" + formatter.format(eDate.getTime()));
            //Log.d(TAG,"today:"+formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()));
            //Log.d(TAG,m.group(2));}
            locationn.add(location);
            typee.add(type);
            namee.add(name);
            strt.add(eventStartDate);
            end.add(eventEndDate);
        }//end of if
```

i cant update ui before finding `gps coordinates` and calculate `distance` and find the closest ones. i only find all places in background.i can not pass the `results` because a lot of arrays about all events. I dont want to use object or wrapper. so i should finish inside `asynctask`. and want to update ui with closest events inside asynctask.

after i update ui, asynctask will finish. when user clicks one of events, how will i retrieve information about it? i dont return anything from asynctask.and asynctask finishes after updating ui. Must i return arrays?

Comment: It is good to paste some code so that we can get idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I guess you should take a look at the `OnPostResult` method of the `ASyncTask`.

Comment: Agree. Check out AsyncTask. There is also a nice example in the official documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

If you want to call a method on your parent, send the parent instance to the AsyncTask through a constructor or through the parameters you can give it. Then call your parent method in OnPostExecute().

Comment: onPostExecute(Result) you meant? it updates ui. i cant update ui before finding gps coordinates and calculate distance and find the closest ones. i only find all places in background.i can not pass the results because a lot of arrays about all events. I dont want to use object or wrapper. so i should finish inside asynctask. and want to update ui with closest events inside

Comment: You do all the heavy work in AsyncTask's doInBackground, and then your UI update stuff in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing you code in total I am having to make some guesses here but the general patter is

```
doInBackGround(){
   // do the work
}

onPostExecute(){
   // update the ui
}
```

for what I think your are hoping to achieve I would recomend that you pass a refeance of your parent class into you Asynctask.

```
// so the constuctor
MapClass parent;
public MyAsyncTask(MapClass map)
{
    this.parent = map
}
```

now if you want to pass data to the parent class you can, so in your map class create a method called for example

```
public void setPlacesToParty(String[] parties){
}
```

now in you you AsyncTask

```
onPostExecute(Sting[] parties){
   parent.setPlacesToParty(parties);
}
```

you will have to modify this to fit your needs

in reference to you specific questions

1) Is it good thing to call parent class method?
-YES off loading the hard work to the background thread will make you app look and feel better

2) answered above I hope

3) i dont return anything from asynctask.and asynctask finishes after updating ui. Must i return arrays? 
-NO you can modify the class to return whatever you want, if you have a very specific data structure you can create a custom class and return array of objects of that class.

Comment: so, passing string arrays to main in the method you mentioned for updating ui in textviews in main  or passing mainmap activty to asynctask postexecute to update ui there?which one, still i cant decide. What i will do is,i will remove map and show all texts. So, for that i created another emptylinear layout, maybe can i use fragment or should i make another class for activity?

Comment: Sorry mike I don’t understand your question? could you clarify it for me

Comment: parent.setPlacesToParty(parties); with those i couldnot understand how i will use parties in parent class.